# OpenGL Context Loss in Service

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-mediacodec, egl

I am continuing work that I referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31527134/controlling-frame-rate-of-virtualdisplay) and have hit a few snags. I have a `VirtualDisplay` that has a `Surface` that the frames are written to and then I use that same surface as input for a `MediaCodec` so that the frames from the `VirtualDisplay` are encoded. This is all occurring in some `Threads` that are running in an Android `Service` **NOT** in an `Activity`.

I now want to add an intermediary `Surface` into the chain so that the progress will go `VirtualDisplay` -> write to `SurfaceA` -> some logic/features -> write to `SurfaceB` -> encode `SurfaceB`

I have created, after much struggle, `SurfaceA` using just straight OpenGL and EGL calls, not using `GLSurfaceView.` I'm using [this](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/RecordFBOActivity.java) as an example of how I should be writing from `SurfaceA` to `SurfaceB`. From my understanding I just need two `EGLSurfaces` in a single `EGLContext`.

From my understanding, the GL context can be lost at any time and I may need to recreate my OpenGL texture (and maybe EGLSurfaces too?). This is usually handled via `GLSurfaceView` but since I am not using one, is there an easy way to know when the context is lost? Should I just use a `GLSurfaceView` even though none of my work involves a `View` or is visible to the user? How do you call `onPause` and `onResume` for a `GLSurfaceView` if there is no `Activity`?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a [SurfaceTexture](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html) (a/k/a GLConsumer), which converts frames arriving on the Surface into GLES textures.  It has no View component.

GLSurfaceView is the worst possible thing to use, as it will create and destroy its EGL context when the Activity pauses and resumes.  (EGL contexts do not get lost -- they go away when they're destroyed.  Don't use GLSurfaceView if you care about the lifespan of your context.)

Various examples of SurfaceTexture use can be found in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika).  You can use one EGL context with two EGL surfaces, or two separate EGL contexts with shared state.  The former is probably easier.

See also the [graphics architecture document](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html).

Comment: Right. I am using a `SurfaceTexture` right now that has no `View` component. I have everything working with so far with no problems. I believe OpenGL contexts can be lost on power down/sleep/etc.

Question was more of "Are OpenGL contexts loss and how to detect when they are?"

Comment: The AOSP code should not throw them away. The GLES driver shouldn't be able to tell the difference between a foreground app and a background app, so I would expect the foreground app to fail if the driver did this. Do you have a reproducible test case showing GLES contexts being lost on power down / sleep? I would expect any GLES operation to result in a "bad context" error from the driver.

Comment: I don't actively see context loss in the code that I have, I just remember dealing with OpenGL context loss when working on previous Android projects (which were games). I also saw a bunch of context loss related questions on SO, so I thought I'd ask. My question was trying to get in front of potential issues.

I currently check for EGL failure coded (one of which is loss of context) when calling swapBuffers and if that fails, grabbing the EGL error and doing context loss behavior there if the error code was context loss.

Comment: If it is a non issue, then I can just close/delete this question. Thanks for the input.