# glReadPixels return 0

Tags: android

I am doing my work about capturing screen and encoding on Android 5.0.
I want to control the frame rate and read this below

[Controlling Frame Rate of VirtualDisplay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31527134/controlling-frame-rate-of-virtualdisplay][1])

I created a SurfaceTexture and a Surface initialised by the SurfaceTexture , and pass the Surface to createVirtualDisplay.

The onFrameAvailable callback fired, almost 60 times per second.

**But when I try to save a frame, the data got from glReadPixels is 0**

Anyone knows about it? Any help would be greatly appreciated!