# VirtualDisplay Screen Flicker

Tags: android, opengl-es

A while back I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31527134/controlling-frame-rate-of-virtualdisplay) and @fadden was gracious enough to give me an answer. So, now I have a `VirtualDisplay` which is using an intermediary `Surface` that I create and when the `SurfaceTexture` that backs the `Surface` receives an `onFrameAvailable` call, I make OpenGL calls to put draw that texture to an EGLSurface which is created from the `Surface` generated by the `MediaCodec`. Phew.

All of this is running in a `Service` (so it sticks around in the background). It all works, but I'm having some screen flickering occasionally on some devices. The flickering does not carry through to the data sent to the `MediaCodec` so it seems to be an issue with just the screen. The flickering also causes the "soft buttons" on Nexus devices to disappear/reappear on Nexus devices (but even when the buttons are gone on screen, the soft buttons appear in the output of the `MediaCodec`.

If I swap out my intermediary `Surface` so that the `VirtualDisplay` just outputs to the `MediaCodec`'s input `Surface` then the flicker happens significantly less (happened one time in 50 or so minutes vs. flickering a few times a second periodically). The flickering also seems to happen in certain apps more so than other apps (Google Maps is a good culprit) or when certain UI appears/disappears in apps.

Anyone have have any ideas on what could cause the flickering in this scenario and only one some devices (that I've seen)? I can post some source code if that would be helpful.

EDIT: So, I've found that, on my Nexus 5x at least, if I go to "Developer Options" and enable "Disable HW Overlays" (the text says "Always use GPU for screen compositing") that the screen flicker goes away. Obviously this is a workaround, but I'd like to fix the issue programatically if at all possible.

Comment: Generally speaking, if "disable HW overlays" makes a problem go away, there's a good chance that the bug is related to the Hardware Composer. (Disabling HWC was one of the first things we always tried when looking at a display bug.) Since it's happening on a Nexus device you can file a bug at http://b.android.com/.